# Is there a way I can access files from an Android app that is saved by another app on a different device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

What  I am trying to achieve here is I want  to use an android device as Accelerometer that calculate running hours of Truck . Basically I have created an app that detects device motion or vibration . The app calculates running hours in minutes if a certain threshold if met  . I am saving the value in a text file in android  . I need to know if is there Wait I can access this file / value from  a different app installed in a different device?. I had a look on Content Providers but what am not sure of is if you can share app data between apps in different device.

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just upload the data to a mysql database and access it from anywhere and any device. You just have to specify the userId and access the informations based on that

Comment: Hi I am trying to eliminate syncing the value back to the server because I might end up getting a wrong the value which was synced when a device was last sync but the accelemeter app is still running a has a new value .

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean, but as far as I know, what you're asking is not possible without some sort of server

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data)

Check out how to get [Firebase on your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)